# How to list all processes that's run as freedesktop.org protocol system tray?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-mint, kde, notification-area

I'm trying to run `wmsystemtray` command but it outputs:

```
wmsystemtray: Another application is already running as the freedesktop.org protocol system tray
wmsystemtray: Could not initialize the freedesktop.org tray protocol
```

So I want to view all processes/commands that use this protocol. How to do it?

Desktop environment: KDE. OS: Linux Mint 18.

P.S. `wmsystemtray` was started successfully before rebooting.

Comment: Are you sure KDE Plasma itself doesn't provide that function?

Comment: I didn't find how to list processes that use freedesktop.org protocol, but I found process `xembedsniproxy` that prevents from `wmsystemtray` running. So  `xembedsniproxy` killing solves the problem.

Comment: `xembedsniproxy` is starting using autostart file: `/etc/xdg/autostart/xembedsniproxy.desktop`, so I removed it.